# Android: Notification action to dismiss the notification

Tags: android, notifications, action

I'm trying to create an android notification with action buttons. I have already set one up which starts an activity, but I would like another which dismisses the notification and doesn't take the user to another screen/Activity (not taken to any part of my app)

I don't want to use '.auto cancel(true) ' because I want the notification to be kept unless this action button is pressed.

The primary use would be for ongoing notifications as they cannot be removed with a swipe.  The idea is similar to the android calender with the 'dismiss' action.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? What API level are you targeting? You should be able to do all this with a jellybean+ notification.

Comment: I am using the jellybean api - I have already made an action that starts an activity, buy I can't work out how to not start an activity. I could use a broadcast receiver, but i dont if that would enable me to clear the notification. Basically I would like a notification action to clear itself ( the notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the notification is created, send the notification to a broadcastreceiver. The broadcast receiver is them started when the notification action is pressed, so the cancel() in the broadcast receiver cancels the notification.

Comment: can you give the exact code for this, i am not able to follow your instructions. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IMO Using a broadcastReceiver is a cleaner way to cancel a Notification:

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
     android:name=.NotificationCancelReceiver" >
     <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
         <action android:name="com.example.cancel" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In java File

```
Intent cancel = new Intent("com.example.cancel");
PendingIntent cancelP = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, cancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Action actions[] = new NotificationCompat.Action[1];
```

NotificationCancelReceiver:

```
public class NotificationCancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //Cancel your ongoing Notification
    }
}
```